# Sporadic lag in Android game

Tags: java, android, lag

I'm making a simple Android game with Java. I noticed some annoying lags every 20-40 seconds. First I thought they we're caused by the Garbage Collector, but as I checked my LogCat I saw that there's no Garbage Collection at the time the game lags.
I marked the log everytime the game begans to lag and saw that there's almost everytime this log entry:

> W/qdhwcomposer(209): Excessive delay reading vsync: took 47 ms

As it says, there is a delay (usually >45ms) and i think that's what I notice as lag.
Does anybody know this problem or how to avoid those delays?

Here are two snippets from LogCat at the time the game lags:

```
07-29 15:11:50.196: D/BatteryService(692): update start
07-29 15:11:50.206: D/BatteryService(692): level:80, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4121, temperature: 355, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303554, invalid charger:0, online:4, charge type:1, current avg:460
07-29 15:11:50.206: D/BatteryService(692): Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
07-29 15:11:50.216: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(1082): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
07-29 15:11:50.216: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(1082): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
07-29 15:11:50.226: D/HeadsetStateMachine(18054): Disconnected process message: 10
07-29 15:11:50.236: W/qdhwcomposer(209): Excessive delay reading vsync: took 47 ms
07-29 15:11:50.236: D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger(1082): checkOverflow(288), More:true, Req:true Child:5

07-29 15:12:00.176: W/qdhwcomposer(209): Excessive delay reading vsync: took 49 ms
07-29 15:12:00.226: D/BatteryService(692): update start
07-29 15:12:00.226: D/BatteryService(692): level:80, scale:100, status:2, health:2, present:true, voltage: 4065, temperature: 355, technology: Li-ion, AC powered:false, USB powered:true, Wireless powered:false, icon:17303554, invalid charger:0, online:4, charge type:1, current avg:460
07-29 15:12:00.226: D/BatteryService(692): Sending ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED.
07-29 15:12:00.236: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(1082): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
07-29 15:12:00.236: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(1082): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
07-29 15:12:00.236: D/HeadsetStateMachine(18054): Disconnected process message: 10
```

I tested it with Android 4.3 on my Samsung Galaxy S4 (GT-I9505) btw.

Thanks
Geru

Comment: BattleCamp has this issue too, it's really annoying as there's a time limit to do the swiping. I have S4 too though, maybe it's just this phone?!

Comment: GERU, have you found a fix?

Comment: As far as I can remember it was really a "Samsung Galaxy S4 specific bug" and I actually don't have this problem on my new phone (Samsung Galaxy A5).
But they don't have the same Android version so I'm not 100% sure if it's hardware related.
Unfortunately my S4 got destroyed last year and I'm unable to test it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging the app using -http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Comment: Well I created a .trace file and read it but I'm not really sure how I can find the cause of my delays in it..