# Android Excessive delay reading vsync

Tags: android, libgdx

I am making an android game using libgdx. I've noticed that after playing some time say 5-10 minutes I occasionally get a sudden unexplained lag in fps. I goes from 60-61 to 40, 35, 25,27 etc. In logcat the error displayed is:

```
  W/qdhwcomposer(209): Excessive delay reading vsync: took 47 ms
  W/qdhwcomposer(209): Excessive delay reading vsync: took 35 ms
  etc.
```

It lasts for about 30 sec up to a few minutes and is very annoying. After that it recovers and I still get around 60 fps. I've profiled my game and there are no dalvik memory reclaims. So the lag is 100% not caused by memory leak. Has anyone found a fix or experienced the issue?

Comment: Did you monitor you CPU/GPU usage? Maybe device for some reason lowered there frequency.

Comment: what could be the reason is the question? I found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25017352/sporadic-lag-in-android-game but with no answer

Comment: It could be  a lot of things and it's hard to say what is causing this in your case. But things that already been mentioned could absolutely be the problem. In addition to HW/Android reasons it can also be power saving or battery features. I had this problem myself for a 3D game with a lot of resources/assets being loaded so if that is your case too, try and see if there is any change in performance if you either unload all unused assets or reduce the size and or amount of them. This issue is one that will not show in CPU/GPU or memory profiling.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't develop any games so not very familiar with VSync topic. However I suggest that lags may occur due to 3 reasons:

1. There's an issue within you code or assets. For example to much objects allocated after 5-10 minutes or specific "heavy" level part/effect being displayed in that moment. If you actively work with touch screen issue may occur because of vast amount of `MotionEvent` being stored in OS's queue waiting for being processed.
2. There's a background `Service` or `BroadcastReceiver` which runs on your device by timer. It may do heavy tasks on UI thread which cause the lags.
3. Device hardware for some reason thinks that you don't need much it's
   power and lows frequency of GPU/CPU or both. This is firmware or hardware   issue. You can enable performance monitor in your device developer settings to check.

Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/testing/performance.html) topic also. It provides information about how you can monitor you UI performance including frame processing on each stage.

Comment: 1 is excluded - as I say there's no CG when the lag happens
 2. is possible since I've got timers. How can I debug that?
 3. possible
However, it could be none of these. So I am more interested whether you know what's causing this issue specifically